# Mysql procedure selecting next date

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm using a MySQL procedure to fetch a open date within a shops opening hours.

My shop has different openening hours for delivery/pickup (delivery_type). In addition I'm using an integer parameter (offset), for increasing current time, incase the shop is really busy. Offset must only be taken into consideration for current day.

Opening hours are defined in table *shop_hours*, as one record matching the day of week (1-7). To add some flexibility I have a seperate table *shop_hours_special* for special dates. This table overrules any opening/close times as defined in shop_hours. *shop_hours_special* is defined as day of year.

**My problem:**

1. CALL nextDate(2, 9999999);

This returns 2012-12-16 (which is today UTC+1), but the offset parameter is so high, that it should push to the next open date e.g. monday, 2012-12-17.

1. CALL nextDate(1,0);

If the shop has opening hours today, but the time for opening is not yet met, it will return the next open day, but really should return todays date.

Can someone please help, with what I'm doing wrong?

---

**PHP Function:**

```
public function get_next_open_date($delivery_type, $offset = 0) {

    $sql = 'CALL nextDate('.$delivery_type.','.$offset.');';
    $date = $this->app['db']->fetchAssoc($sql);

    return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date['final_date']));
}
```

**MySQL Procedure:**

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `nextDate`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `nextDate`(IN dType TINYINT(3), IN dOffset INT)
BEGIN

    DECLARE CURTIME TIME;
    DECLARE final_date DATE;
    DECLARE match_found, closed_day BOOLEAN;
    DECLARE dYear, dWeek, dayYear, dayWeek, contor INT;

    SET contor = 0;
    SET match_found = TRUE;
    SET dayYear = DAYOFYEAR(NOW());
    SET dayWeek = WEEKDAY(NOW()) + 1;
    SET dYear = -1;
    SET dWeek = -1;
    SET CURTIME = ADDTIME(TIME(NOW()),SEC_TO_TIME(dOffset));

    WHILE match_found DO

        SET closed_day = FALSE;
        IF contor = 0 THEN
            SELECT IFNULL(a.day_of_year, -1), IF(open_time = MAKETIME(0,0,0) AND close_time = MAKETIME(0,0,0), TRUE, FALSE) INTO dYear, closed_day
                FROM shop_hours_special a
                WHERE a.`type` = dType AND a.day_of_year = dayYear
                    AND (CURTIME BETWEEN a.open_time AND a.close_time OR (open_time = MAKETIME(0,0,0) AND close_time = MAKETIME(0,0,0)));       

            SELECT IFNULL(b.day_of_week, -1) INTO dWeek
                FROM shop_hours b
                WHERE b.`type` = dType AND b.day_of_week = dayWeek AND (b.open_time != MAKETIME(0,0,0) OR b.close_time != MAKETIME(0,0,0)) AND CURTIME BETWEEN b.open_time AND b.close_time ;

        ELSE
            SELECT IFNULL(a.day_of_year, -1), IF(open_time = MAKETIME(0,0,0) AND close_time = MAKETIME(0,0,0), TRUE, FALSE) INTO dYear, closed_day
                FROM shop_hours_special a
                WHERE a.`type` = dType AND a.day_of_year = dayYear;

            SELECT IFNULL(b.day_of_week, -1) INTO dWeek
                FROM shop_hours b
                WHERE b.`type` = dType AND b.day_of_week = dayWeek AND (b.open_time != MAKETIME(0,0,0) OR b.close_time != MAKETIME(0,0,0));
        END IF;

        IF closed_day THEN
            SET dYear = -1;
            SET dWeek = -1;
        END IF;     

        IF dYear != -1 THEN
            SET final_date = MAKEDATE(YEAR(NOW()), dYear);
            SET match_found = FALSE;

        ELSEIF dWeek != -1 THEN

            SET final_date = NOW() + INTERVAL contor DAY;
            SET match_found = FALSE;

        ELSE
            SET contor = contor + 1;
            SET dayYear = DAYOFYEAR(NOW() + INTERVAL contor DAY);
            SET dayWeek = WEEKDAY(NOW() + INTERVAL contor DAY) + 1; 

        END IF;

    END WHILE;

    SELECT final_date;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**Sample data:**

```
CREATE TABLE `shop_hours` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `shop_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `day_of_week` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `open_time` time NOT NULL,
  `close_time` time NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `shop_id` (`shop_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `shop_hours_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`shop_id`) REFERENCES `shops` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `shop_hours` (`id`, `shop_id`, `type`, `day_of_week`, `open_time`, `close_time`)
VALUES
    (1,1,1,1,'09:30:00','20:00:00'),
    (2,1,1,2,'09:30:00','20:00:00'),
    (3,1,1,3,'09:30:00','20:00:00'),
    (4,1,1,4,'09:30:00','20:00:00'),
    (5,1,1,5,'09:30:00','20:00:00'),
    (6,1,1,6,'09:30:00','20:00:00'),
    (7,1,1,7,'11:00:00','20:00:00'),
    (8,1,2,1,'11:30:00','12:30:00'),
    (9,1,2,2,'11:30:00','12:30:00'),
    (10,1,2,3,'11:30:00','12:30:00'),
    (11,1,2,4,'11:30:00','12:30:00'),
    (12,1,2,5,'11:30:00','12:30:00'),
    (13,1,2,6,'00:00:00','00:00:00'),
    (14,1,2,7,'00:01:00','23:00:00');

CREATE TABLE `shop_hours_special` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `shop_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `day_of_year` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `open_time` time NOT NULL,
  `close_time` time NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique` (`shop_id`,`type`,`day_of_year`),
  KEY `shop_id` (`shop_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `shop_hours_special_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`shop_id`) REFERENCES `shops` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `shop_hours_special` (`id`, `shop_id`, `type`, `day_of_year`, `open_time`, `close_time`)
VALUES
    (1,1,1,1,'00:00:00','00:00:00'),
    (2,1,1,92,'00:00:00','00:00:00'),
    (3,1,1,96,'00:00:00','00:00:00'),
    (4,1,1,97,'00:00:00','00:00:00'),
    (5,1,1,99,'00:00:00','00:00:00'),
    (6,1,1,100,'00:00:00','00:00:00'),
    (7,1,1,125,'00:00:00','00:00:00'),
    (8,1,1,138,'00:00:00','00:00:00'),
    (9,1,1,148,'00:00:00','00:00:00'),
    (10,1,1,149,'00:00:00','00:00:00'),
    (11,1,2,1,'00:00:00','00:00:00'),
    (12,1,2,92,'00:00:00','00:00:00'),
    (13,1,2,96,'00:00:00','00:00:00'),
    (14,1,2,97,'00:00:00','00:00:00'),
    (15,1,2,99,'00:00:00','00:00:00'),
    (16,1,2,100,'00:00:00','00:00:00'),
    (17,1,2,125,'00:00:00','00:00:00'),
    (18,1,2,138,'00:00:00','00:00:00'),
    (19,1,2,148,'00:00:00','00:00:00'),
    (20,1,2,149,'00:00:00','00:00:00');
```

Comment: The PHP function is not relevant, but added just as a precaution